# Multiplying numbers in two's complement

Tags: arithmetic, binary

I have $2$ numbers, both in two's complement form. The problem is $101011 \cdot{100111}$.
I already sign extended the multiplicand to 2n bits, making it $111111101011$. I arrived at my answer, $110100001101$ which is **wrong!** Can anyone work this through or explain to me a different approach? Thanks.

Comment: Ugh...  Multiplication based on specific interpretation of number systems.  Have you tried converting each directly to integers prior to multiplying, then converting back to twos-complement form at the end?

Comment: I haven't because it's part of a homework problem and I think that would defeat the purpose.